# Styled Components: Override Styles not working correctly with Server Side Rendering

Tags: styled-components, server-side-rendering

It seems like overriding styles does not work consistently. I have this two styled components:

```
const StreamContentContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  vertical-align: middle;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 0 100%;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 1rem;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
`;

// new Component based on StreamContentContainer 
with additional styles and override stlye

const FullStreamContentContainer = styled(StreamContentContainer)`
  height: 56.11vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
`;
```

Know if I use my `FullStreamContentContainer` there should be no padding. On CSR that works fine, the element shows up in the markup correctly. 
But if the element is requested initial with SSR the padding of the `StreamContentContainer` overrides the `FullStreamContentContainer` again.
It does not matter if the node is generated on SSR or CSR, it shows up the same way in the markup: 
`<div class="sc-4y67w2-1 fodYop sc-4y67w2-0 WzHos">...</div>`.
But if I inspect the element with the DevTools, I can see that on SSR first the class `WzHos` shows up and then the class `fodYop`:

[image: Styles on SSR]

Compared to the rules rendered on CSR the rules occur the other way round - like expected: [image: Styles on CSR]

Does anybody know what causes this weird behavior and how to avoid it?

Comment: did you configure server with styled-components ? 

Here an article who can help you : https://medium.com/styled-components/the-simple-guide-to-server-side-rendering-react-with-styled-components-d31c6b2b8fbf

Article says to create a `ServerStyleSheet ` , hope it could help you.

Comment: @Deve yes I did. And thats working. All styles are collected, nothing is missing and they are all included but I guess something with the priority of the styles is messing up. I can't figure out why that is only happening on SSR and not on CSR.

Answer (score 3):

Problem resolved: Increased the specificity of FullStreamContentContainer styles by using

```
const FullStreamContentContainer = styled(StreamContentContainer)`
  &&& {
  height: 56.11vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  }
`;
```

Relating [to the SC docs](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/faqs#how-can-i-override-styles-with-higher-specificity), the repeated class bumps the specificity high enough to override the source order.

Comment: Nice solution. Hacky, but it's necessary because of Styled Components `SeverStylesheet` implementation. I'm going to open an issue with them.

Comment: This solution seemed to be working, thanks for posting this. However I'm not sure why this problem occured, I mean I had this working in my prod app with nextjs 10, only after upgrading to nextjs12 it has started to cause issues. Styled component dependency was same in both the next versions though